# Conditional positional comparison of lists based on

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a similar question recently, but the error message and problem changed a bit.

I would like to create multiple lists that are dependent on the previous list based on the position of items in each list

So for example list 1 would read a specific file and return either a number or the boolean false based on a comparison.

The second list would then compare the number that appears in the same position as those in the previous list (if the value from the previous list was not false) and return the value or false based on the same comparison as the first list

Examples of dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([0,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8])
b = pd.DataFrame([0.7,0.51,0.3,0.7,0.2])
```

I created a function that carries out these comparisons and creates a list

```
def generic_state_machine(file,obs_nums):
    return file.ix[:,0][obs_nums] if file.ix[:,0][obs_nums] > 0.2 else False
```

obs_nums in this context refers to the position of an item in a list

I then created the lists that look at different files

```
session_to_leads = []
lead_to_opps = []

for i in range(1,len(a)):
     session_to_leads.append(generic_state_machine(file=a,obs_nums=i))
     lead_to_opps.append(generic_state_machine(file=b,obs_nums=i)) if session_to_leads != False else lead_to_opps.append(False)
```

I managed to sort out the initial error I encountered, the only problem now is that list lead_to_opps is not dependent on session_to_leads so if there is a False value in position 1, lead_to_opps will not automatically return a False in the same position. So assuming that random.uniform(0,1) generates 0.5 all the time, this is my current outcome:

```
session_to_leads = [False,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8]
lead_to_opps = [0.7,0.51,False,0.7,False]
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
session_to_leads = [False,0.9,0.6,0.7,0.8]
lead_to_opps = [False,0.51,False,0.7,False]
```

Comment: The part of your code: 
   `if session_to_leads != False`
refers to the whole list and not the positional part of the list. You need to either compare to that element of the list or recalculate it like: 
   `if generic_state_machine(file=a,obs_nums=i) != False`

Comment: @zcoleman outcomes seems to be the same

Comment: @zcoleman I'm assuming when I add if generic_state_machine(file=a,obs_nums=i) it reruns random.uniform(0,1) in my function....not retaining the random number generated initially?

Comment: I got the code to work by applying that fix and by starting the loop at the index 0 instead of `range(1,len(a))`. This gave me expected results.

Comment: The ternary operator won't call the function unless its in conditional. Here's simple example `print('foo') if False else print('test')` and 

`print('foo') if True else print('test')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand your requirement and your intention is not clear. You already created dataframes from the list. You just need to work directly on dataframe `a` and `b`. Here the way works with dataframe `a` and `b`

```
m = a > 0.2
session_to_leads = a.where(a > 0.2, False)[0].to_list()

Out[755]: [False, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
```

After having `session_to_leads`, use the the same condition on `b` combine with condition `m`

```
lead_to_opps = b.where((b > 0.2) & m, False)[0].to_list()
Out[769]: [False, 0.51, 0.3, 0.7, False]
```

**Note**: the 3rd element of `lead_to_opps` is `0.3` instead of `False` as in your desired ouput because the condition is `> 0.2` and `True` in   `session_to_leads`